# Extjs 4 treeStore appendChild after a specific node

Tags: extjs4.1, treegrid

How to append a child on a specific position (as default the new child will appear after the last node)

---

My solution is to use  a variable of order

```
function treeGridReorder(){
        var i=0 ,j = 0;
        treeGrid.getView().getStore().each(function(node){
            node.data.ordre=i;
            j=0;
            node.eachChild(function(cnode){
                cnode.data.ordre=j;
                j++;
            });
            i++;
        })
    }
```

---

```
function add_reponse(quest, qIndex){
        questStr.sort('ordre', 'ASC');
        var now=new Date().getTime();
        questStr.getNodeById(quest).appendChild({id:now, libelle:'Nouvelle réponse',parentq:quest,  saved:false, leaf: true});
        treeGridReorder()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-insertChild ?  This takes an index parameter.

Comment: Thank you @dbrin the problem 'insertChild' insert it on the store so in the view this doesn't have any effect , i wanna the position of the node on the view

Comment: sure it has effect. the view is bound to the store, try it.

Comment: I fixed the problem by using a new variable that contains the order of each row on the view , the problem is that the order of the view.store isn't the same with the order of the grid.store, the order is the same when you start but if you drag or drop rows or delete them the order of the view will change but the order of the store still the same

Comment: That should be automatically handled via idProperty. Can you please add your solution in the edit section of the Question?